# Sharing files between iPhones and PC

Tags: iphone, import, export, file-sharing

Im looking to see how I can share / export content from my app to allow the content to be imported in the app running on another device.

Something like if you get emailed a pdf file or word file it opens in the correct app when tapped.

I tried using the iTunes sharing approach but that allowed full access to the apps documents folder which allowed the user to mess around with content they should not be allowed to!

The content in the app will be a bundled group of images, text and audio so could be large in size so was thinking of how to transfer easily from within the app to a PC of some file sharing service that would allow the target user to then select this content from within there app and have it imported available to use.

Is this a big ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1Password app uses DropBox and it seems to work quiet well.